# SVG `fill` overlaps `stroke`

Tags: css, svg, fill, stroke

Having a circle it has `fill` and `stroke`. But I see that `fill` color overlaps little bit `stroke`. When I do `stroke` to `none`, I loose circle radius that was before, since its space released.

[image]

I expected that `fill` and `stroke` behaves the same as `background` and `border` in CSS, but it's not.
I can't set them the same color with the same opacity, since `fill` will overlap `stroke` and I will see another color to be appeared.

[image]

Both `fill` and `stroke` set to red with the same opacity.

How I can do, so `fill` stops right where `stroke` is starting (having `fill` and `stroke` the same color and opacity), and I have flat color without any borders?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `stroke-alignment` though it's a never implemented CSS feature — see https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-strokes/#SpecifyingStrokeAlignment.

For simple geometry, you can achieve this by duplicating the structure and adjusting.

```css
#c1 {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
  stroke: none;
}
#c2 {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle id="c1" cx="20" cy="20" r="11.5" stroke-width="3"></circle>
  <circle id="c2" cx="20" cy="20" r="13" stroke-width="3"></circle>
</svg>
```

Or by changing the opacity at the element, not the attributes.

```css
svg circle {
  opacity: 0.3;
  fill: red;
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="13" stroke-width="3"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, actually. You can use:

```
paint-order: stroke;
```

that will first paint the stroke on the canvas and then paint the fill.

Comment: With both the fill and stroke being semi-transparent, would the paint order matter?